# Facebook HTTP Request JS API Error on 0-278 channel facebook.com

Tags: facebook, fbjs

Have anyone had this problem before using the Facebook JavaScript API for a page tab like-gateway and face long time waiting for this URL request:  0-278.channel.facebook.com!

I'm not sure where to begin attacking this problem since its a downtime on Facebook. Any ideas of a work around.

[Screenshot from an HTTP sniffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDBW2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The requests to these domains are not related to the tab app, and has no effect on your application. You can safely ignore these.